# Piece-wise probability density and cumulative distribution function exercise

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a random variable $X$ with the density function:

$f(x) = a$ if $0 \leq x \leq b$      and

$f(x) = b$ if $b < x < a + b$

I want to solve the following exercises regarding this distribution:

a) How large is $a$ if $b = 3a$?

b) $a = 0.5, b = 1$, then:

i) What is $P(X>1)$?

ii) What is $P(0.8<X<1.2)$

iii) What is $x_1$ s.t. $ P(X<x_1) = 0.05$?

c) Calculate $F(x)$

My ideas:

**a)** The area under the function has to sum up to $1$, hence I assume that $6a^2 = 1$ and hence $a = \sqrt{1/6}$ — is that correct?

**b)**

i) $[\frac{1}{2}x^2]_1^{1.5}$

ii) $ 0.5 * [\frac{1}{2}x^2]_{0.8}^{1} + [\frac{1}{2}x^2]_1^{1.2}$

iii) My idea would to solve for b in $\int_{0}^b f(x) x dx = 0.5 $ — but how exactly would I formulate $f(x)$?

c) I would assume we end up with two $F(x)$, each one being the integral of the respective $f(x)$ and hence $0.5x$ and $x$ respectively, is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: At a) I have the same result.

Comment: I have made an edit.

Comment: What about iii)? Also, you dont have the same result for the cdf as the other commentator

Comment: I have made an edit for iii).  And the calculations for the cdf at $0\leq x\leq1$

Answer (score 1):

Your value for (a) is correct.

For (b), it seems you have somehow derived the wrong CDF $F(x)$.  The PDF $f(x)$ is piecewise constant:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \hfill \frac{1}{2} \hfill & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
    \hfill 1 \hfill & 1 < x < \frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

(It looks like an L rotated $90$ degrees counter-clockwise.)  You seem to have assumed that the PDF was

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \hfill \frac{x}{2} \hfill & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
    \hfill x-\frac{1}{2} \hfill & 1 < x < \frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

However, seemingly, you have produced the correct CDF $F(x)$ in part (c); it is, in fact,

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
    \hfill \frac{x}{2} \hfill & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
    \hfill x-\frac{1}{2} \hfill & 1 < x < \frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

That is, exactly what you seem to have used for $f(x)$ in part (b).

Comment: Thank you. However, your cdf seems to differ from the cdf as suggested by the other commentator (they say x - 0.5 for the interval 1 < x < 3/2). Also, what about iii)? Many thanks

Comment: They are correct. I'll fix mine.

Comment: So, why is it for that interval x - 1/2 and not just x, as the integral of 1 would just be x?

Comment: The integral of $1$ *is* $x$—plus a constant.  In this case, the constant is $-1/2$.  The reason for that is the boundary condition from the previous interval: Since there are no impulses anywhere in the PDF, the CDF must be continuous at $x = 1$, so $x/2 = x+C$ at $x = 1$.  This yields $C = -1/2$.  As for (iii), $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$, so you simply want the value of $x$ such that $F(x) = 0.05$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The cdf is

$$ F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \  \text{if} \  x < 0  \\  \int_{0}^x 0.5 \, dt, \  \text{if} \ 0  \leq x \leq 1 \\  \int_{0}^1 0.5 \, dt+\int_1^{x} 1 \, dt, \  \text{if} \ 1 < x < 1.5 \\ 1, \  \text{if} \  x \geq 1.5\end{cases}$$

$$\Rightarrow F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \  \text{if} \  x < 0  \\  0.5x, \  \text{if} \ 0  \leq x \leq 1 \\  x-0.5, \  \text{if} \ 1 < x < 1.5 \\ 1, \  \text{if} \  x \geq 1.5\end{cases}$$

$\int_{0}^1 0.5 \, dt=0.5t\bigg|_0^1=0.5-0=0.5$

$\int_1^{x} 1 \, dt=t\bigg|_1^x=x-1$

$0.5+(x-1)=x+0.5-1=x-0.5$

**ad iii)**

You know that $P(X\leq 1)=0.5$. Thus $x_1$ has to be in the interval $[0,1]$

$P(X <x_1)=0.5x_1=0.05 \Rightarrow x_1=\frac{0.05}{0.5}=0.1$